# Trying to make an object that stores an ObservableArrayList extend RealmObject, but Android project does not compile

Tags: java, android, data-binding, realm, android-databinding

I have an object like so:

```
public class SubredditAddition extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String mSubredditName;

    private ObservableArrayList<Keyword> mKeywords = new ObservableArrayList<>();
}
```

When I try to compile the program, I get the following error from Gradle:

```
Error:(13, 8) error: Field "mKeywords" of type "android.databinding.ObservableArrayList<Keyword>" is not supported.

Warning:Unclosed files for the types '[io.realm.SubredditAdditionRealmProxy]'; these types will not undergo annotation processing
```

Is there any way I can store an ObservableArrayList in realm?

Comment: Great question, I have the same problem

Comment: You can see the error log above: `ObservableArrayList<Keyword>" is not supported`. If you want to use ArrayList inside  RealmObject, you can use `RealmList.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it be creating an empty class like so:

```
public class RealmObservableArrayList<T> extends ObservableArrayList implements RealmModel {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ObservableArrayList or ArrayList or any java Collection in any Realm Object.

You have to use RealmList instead of ObservableArrayList.

Alos make sure Keyword must not be inner class (must be in outside scope of SubredditAddition) and extends RealmObject